# Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args - while creating - new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "image/jpeg");

Tags: java, android, servlets, server

I have been trying to tranfer an image with my android app to my servlet server side, and i get this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;
```

I am using a code i've found on google, and this is as far as I got.

IDE - android studio

android side code

Model_Servlet.java:

```
    public Boolean uploadBook(Book newBook) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap bookPic = newBook.getBookPic();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bookPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url + "/BookUploadServlet");

    String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    ByteArrayBody bookImage = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "image/jpeg");
    StringBody sbOwner = new StringBody(newBook.getBookName(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
            .setBoundary(boundary)
            .addPart("bookname", sbOwner)
            .addPart("bookpic", bookImage)
            .build();

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    return false;
}
```

java servlet code:
BookUploadServlet.java:

```
public class BookUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public BookUploadServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    { 
          Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
          if (parts.size() != 3) {
             //can write error page saying all details are not entered 
           } 

           Part filePart = request.getPart("bookpic");
           InputStream imageInputStream = filePart.getInputStream();

           //read imageInputStream 
           filePart.write("somefiepath");
           //can also write the photo to local storage 

           //Read Name, String Type  
           Part namePart = request.getPart("bookname");
           if(namePart.getSize() > 20){
               //write name cannot exceed 20 chars 
           } 
           //use nameInputStream if required         
           InputStream nameInputStream = namePart.getInputStream();
           //name , String type can also obtained using Request parameter  
           String nameParameter = request.getParameter("bookname");
           System.out.println(nameParameter);

           //Similialrly can read age properties 
           Part agePart = request.getPart("age");
           int ageParameter = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));



        }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

full error log:

> com.example.liran.tbookandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   AsyncTask #4
>                                                    Process: com.example.liran.tbookandroid, PID: 28111
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.(AbstractContentBody.java:48)
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.(ByteArrayBody.java:74)
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.(ByteArrayBody.java:67)
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.(ByteArrayBody.java:87)
>                                                        at com.example.liran.tbookandroid.AModel.Servlet_Model.Model_Servlet.uploadBook(Model_Servlet.java:159)
>                                                        at com.example.liran.tbookandroid.UploadBookPage.UploadBookFragment$uploadNewBook.doInBackground(UploadBookFragment.java:160)
>                                                        at com.example.liran.tbookandroid.UploadBookPage.UploadBookFragment$uploadNewBook.doInBackground(UploadBookFragment.java:148)
>                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.http.util.Args" on path: DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9_1f22eaf94d6a43c1ed432080a5b4c5afe2850a57-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8_ab0226f587aa519424470ed5fcf18d3a05fde22f-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7_24ad75e4f6545fb5014b20c8d60b41818234b063-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6_f630f64998260b15c9a69a940a52078c80cc85a3-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5_a93ca339627382ab74e183b50d68cf45bfc4b916-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4_7f8feb0cee3e2f31f6d27354b6279c862b2f8ab3-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3_9102e6ca9566d990f4b8640b615b08a6b9c4fc93-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2_9d47b22d0a188feb20bfc04b87009f4fb122a1cc-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1_7560ea8962702ed20df197e30822ea640c944a69-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0_c101d1c9924f3549a1fad0ddc31ef7aa5ac3108c-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.example.liran.tbookandroid/files/instant-run/dex/slice-dependencies_636869a87c346418d26110ccf059f37768a7fdf1-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                        at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.(AbstractContentBody.java:48) 
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.(ByteArrayBody.java:74) 
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.(ByteArrayBody.java:67) 
>                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.(ByteArrayBody.java:87) 
>                                                        at com.example.liran.tbookandroid.AModel.Servlet_Model.Model_Servlet.uploadBook(Model_Servlet.java:159) 
>                                                        at com.example.liran.tbookandroid.UploadBookPage.UploadBookFragment$uploadNewBook.doInBackground(UploadBookFragment.java:160) 
>                                                        at com.example.liran.tbookandroid.UploadBookPage.UploadBookFragment$uploadNewBook.doInBackground(UploadBookFragment.java:148) 
>                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "org.apache.http.util.Args" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.liran.tbookandroid-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Clas

libraries list:

```
httpclient-4.2.3.jar
httpcore-4.2.3.jar
httpmime-4.3.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

if you guys think there's a better code for me for uploading the pic or better code for the servlet side, please help me and tell me.
this is the first time i'm dealling with this sort of stuff(server side), so i'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: The stack trace appears to show that the error occurs in the course of preparing the HTTP request, prior to anything being sent to the servlet.  In that case, the servlet code you've presented is a red herring -- it is not involved.

Comment: Yes, i figured. I just wanted the permission of some one who knows that my servlet code is ok and that i can work with it. Because seriously i don't know that much about that.

Comment: It is suspicious that you have a different version of `httpmime` than of `httpclient` and `httpcore`.  The versions of all these do not necessarily have to be identical, but they are *not* independent.  The docs for your versions should tell you exactly what the dependencies are, with version numbers, or you could just take the empirical approach and standardize on identical versions.

Comment: So you're saying that the problem is the diffrent versions bwtween the jars? i tried changing the versions so the all be look alike and i get another error because of methods that doesn't exists anymore

Comment: I am *speculating* that the problem is that the API versions are not compatible, and that the correct API version numbers are reflected in the jar names.  The latter, at least, will certainly be the case if these are the Apache HTTP components, and the jars and their names came directly from Apache.  The jar names themselves matter to Java only insomuch as your classpath must contain the names of all the jars you need.